# Is there a way to look inside the NLTK or Keras functions in Jupiter Notebook?

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, nltk

Looking for a way to select a function and "open" it to see the code inside of it in Jupiter Notebook. Thanks in advance, a newly joined member here.

As a side note related to the question, the way to see just the description of a given function that I used before was the following:

```
import pydoc
pydoc.help(print) # to see the description of the 'print' function
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, Anscandance. I would suggest adding some example code to your question to demonstrate the problem you're trying to solve. That always makes it easier for people to provide a useful answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `inspect.getsource`

for example, to see the contents of `nltk.word_tokenize`

```
from nltk import word_tokenize
import inspect

lines = inspect.getsource(word_tokenize)
print(lines)
```

Output:

```
def word_tokenize(text, language="english", preserve_line=False):
    """
    Return a tokenized copy of *text*,
    using NLTK's recommended word tokenizer
    (currently an improved :class:`.TreebankWordTokenizer`
    along with :class:`.PunktSentenceTokenizer`
    for the specified language).

    :param text: text to split into words
    :type text: str
    :param language: the model name in the Punkt corpus
    :type language: str
    :param preserve_line: An option to keep the preserve the sentence and not sentence tokenize it.
    :type preserve_line: bool
    """
    sentences = [text] if preserve_line else sent_tokenize(text, language)
    return [
        token for sent in sentences for token in _treebank_word_tokenizer.tokenize(sent)
    ]
```

Comment: Thank you for the guidance, I will start doing that. And, oh my, this is exactly what I had been looking for! Thank you so much, it's amazing :)

Comment: @Anscandance no problem. To mark an answer as accepted, click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.

Comment: thank you for guidance as well. I voted on the answer, it has been registered but will not be visible because I don't have enough reputation yet. Will make sure it has my vote when I have enough reputation.